# Associating supplemental form data with a user object in Django

Tags: django, forms, models, django-allauth

I want to let users registered on my website to submit "project listings" via a django form. I'm using django-allauth. After submitting this form, I want the data to be rendered on a unique URL, which can be browsed by the public.

my template:

```
<form class="listing" id="listing_form" method="post" action="">
  {{ form.as_p }}
 <input type="hidden" name="{{ redirect_field_name }}" value="/" />
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

my form:

```
from django.forms import ModelForm
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _
from account.models import EmailAddress
from account.conf import settings
from projectListing.models import ProjectListing



class ProjectListingForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = ProjectListing
        fields = ('company', 'title', 'short_description',      'full_description', 'skills_required', 'hours_per_week', 'number_of_weeks', 'start_date', 'end_date', 'location')
```

my model:

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from django.conf import settings
from django.db import models
from employerProfiles import models as employerModels


class ProjectListing(models.Model):
    company = models.ForeignKey(employerModels.EmployerProfile)

    title = models.CharField(max_length = 200)
    short_description = models.CharField(max_length = 200)
    full_description = models.TextField()
    skills_required = models.TextField()
    photo = models.ImageField(upload_to='uploads/listingPhotos')
    hours_per_week = models.DecimalField(max_digits=4, decimal_places=2)
    number_of_weeks = models.IntegerField()
    start_date = models.DateField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False)
    end_date = models.DateField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.company
```

What would be the best way to approach this? Thanks!